# How to create a form, using a function, located inside a class

Tags: forms

Usually when we need to create a form we create a function inside module and call:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('function_name');
drupal_render($form);
```

Now I started using entities and created a subclass of `EntityDefaultUIController`. With a form generating function:

```
class transactionUIController extends EntityDefaultUIController {
  public function overviewForm($form, &$form_state) {
     //blah blah
     return $form;
  }
}
```

I need to get this from in an external module. What should I pass to `drupal_get_form` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form callbacks provided by the entity module. So for your example (assuming your entity_type is named 'transaction') you would call drupal_get_form like so:

```
drupal_get_form('entity_ui_overview_form', 'transaction');
```

You can find other Entity UI form related functions [here](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21entity%21includes%21entity.ui.inc/7).